# "call to undefined function imagecreatetruecolor" error in PHP & pChart

Tags: php

I am trying to integrate "pChart" with my PHP code. When I am trying to run the samples it gives me an error stating `call to undefined function imagecreatetruecolor`. The suggestion solution was to load this dll "php_gd2.dll" so I have uncommented `extension=php_gd2.dll` in php.ini file.

Even after that I get the same error. I have tried restarting the server & machine too.

Comment: use `get_defined_functions` to seek for function `imagecreatetruecolor`

Comment: are you sure that `gd` is set up ok? is it listed in `phpinfo()`?

Comment: @kartnik Could you accept/comment on the answer?

Answer (score 49):

Use the following code to test if you have GD extension:

```
<?php
$testGD = get_extension_funcs("gd"); // Grab function list 
if (!$testGD){ echo "GD not even installed."; exit; }
echo"<pre>".print_r($testGD,true)."</pre>";
```

If you get the message that it's not installed, then check the following steps:

1. `phpinfo()` and look up php.ini path
2. edit `php.ini`: extension_dir=<path to your extensions>
3. edit `php.ini`: extension=php_gd2.dll //uncomment or add
4. Restart web server
5. Run the test script again

Comment: Thanks, I resolved it by adding the PHP Path(c:\PHP) in environmental PATH variable

Answer (score 35):

In Ubuntu/Linux Mint Platform (under root), use the following command:

```
apt-get update && apt-get -y install php5-gd
```

Comment: On Ubuntu its `sudo apt-get install php5-gd && sudo service apache2 restart`

Comment: or `sudo apt install php-gd` on ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 16):

For PHP 7.2

```
sudo apt-get install php7.2-gd
```

Comment: Please add some context to your answer - what do you want to solve through installing a package?

Comment: It is a GD function - so you need the GD extension for PHP in order to use it. Above it is a common installation example (ubuntu)

Comment: Thanks for this answer. But as of 2020, you need to use `php-gd` without specifying a version.

Answer (score 4):

I met this problem just now.
You should exec `sudo apt install php7.0-gd` or vim your php.ini 
reopen extension=php_gd2.dll

Answer (score 4):

This answer is an update 9 years later, but PHP has changed a lot.  Please upvote the St. Woland from which this is derived...

Use the following code on your web server to test if you have GD extension:

```
<?php
    $testGD = get_extension_funcs("gd"); // Grab function list 
    if (!$testGD){
        echo "GD not even installed.";
        phpinfo();  // Display the php configuration for the web server
        exit;
    }
    echo"<pre>".print_r($testGD,true)."</pre>";  //display GD function list
```

If you get the message that it's not installed, then check the following steps:

1. Look at the output of phpinfo() to identify your php.ini
2. Edit `php.ini` and enable the GD extension:

   - Newer PHP (7.3, fg):

     - extension=gd2  //uncomment
   - Older PHP (5.x, 7.0, you should upgrade):

     - extension_dir=<path to your extensions> //uncomment or add
     - extension=php_gd2.dll //uncomment or add
3. GD for 7.x may not be installed

   - (for Ubuntu like OS'es) `sudo apt install php7.3-gd` # replace version to yours
4. Restart web server
5. Run the test script again
6. (Remove test script when all is working, it can be a security hole)

As you can see the exact method is very version dependent.  I hope this additional information can help others sort out the exact steps they might need.

Answer (score 3):

i have many version of php and i use the php-fpm. for me for php 8.0 helped is uncomment `;extension=gd` in /etc/php/8.0/cli/php.ini and uncomment `;extension=gd2` in /etc/php/8.0/fpm/php.ini then install gd library as `sudo apt-get install php8.0-gd`.

Answer (score 1):

I have same error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function imagecreatetruecolor() in /var/www/webphp/php/captcha.php on line 251
```

and my solution was this:

```
$ locate php.ini
    /etc/php56/php.ini
```

edit file **php.ini** and uncomment line content "**extension=gd.so**", save and try again

Answer (score 1):

**Update for 2022:**
If you run into this problem with PHP 8.0.0 or more recent versions, then check out the [Image Installation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/image.installation.php) page at PHP's website.

> In Windows, you'll include the GD DLL php_gd.dll as an extension in php.ini. Prior to PHP 8.0.0, the DLL was named php_gd2.dll.

Edit your php.ini file & make sure that this line exists. If not, add it. If it has a `;` before it, remove the semi-colon.

**PHP 8.0.0 or NEWER** If you use [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org), then this file *WILL* exist on your file system:

```
extension=php_gd.dll
```

*Older PHP versions* will use this. If you use [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org) 8.0.0+, then this file *WON'T* exist on your file system:

```
extension=php_gd2.dll
```

That's how you can fix this again. Enjoy!

Comment: In my case, it was the `;extension=gd` line and I removed `;` to uncomment it and then reruned Apache.