# Yii Captcha error

Tags: php, yii, validation, captcha

I am working in Yii and I am just a beginner and trying my best to learn the framework and here is where I am stuck at :

I have created a user model and the required forms that go with it, and I am trying to implement the Captcha for it :

This is my validation rules in the user model :

```
$public verifyCode

public function rules()
    {
        // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
        // will receive user inputs.
        return array(
            array('username, password, email', 'required'),
            array('username','unique'),
            array('email','email'),
            array('verifyCode', 'captcha', 'allowEmpty'=>!CCaptcha::checkRequirements()),
            array('username, password', 'length', 'max'=>45),
            array('email', 'length', 'max'=>100),
            array('active', 'length', 'max'=>1),
            array('created_on, updated_on', 'safe'),
            // The following rule is used by search().
            // Please remove those attributes that should not be searched.
            array('id, username, password, email, created_on, updated_on, active', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
        );
    }
```

And this is my overriden action() in my userController :

```
public function actions(){
        return array(
        'captcha'=>array(
            'class' => 'CCaptchaAction',
            )
            );
    }
```

And this is my view file :

```
<?php if(CCaptcha::checkRequirements()): ?>
    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'verifyCode'); ?>
        <div>
        <?php $this->widget('CCaptcha'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($model,'verifyCode'); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="hint">Please enter the letters as they are shown in the image above.
        <br/>Letters are not case-sensitive.</div>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'verifyCode'); ?>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

According to me, I think that I am doing everything correctly however, the captcha image is not getting generated. Oh and yes the GD library is installed and if I navigate to the site/contact, there the captcha is generated fine.

I dont seem to understand, where am i getting it wrong.

This is the thing that I see :

[image]

The forms seems to be working fine however, I cant see the the captcha image.

Any help would be appreciated.

Regards,

Comment: There is probably access rights to `CCaptchaAction` issue. Have you looked at [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11971926/506695)?

Comment: Also check if you have `gd` library in php. Try to get image directly, and see if you have any error, download image to your pc and check it's contents, there could be some hint too.

Comment: gd is ok, because `CCapcha::checkRequirements()` returns true

Comment: I got the answer, it is because I had not modified my controller code.

Comment: after modifying my controller accessRules but the captcha image not displaying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer, it is because of the access rules that are defined in the controller, I had to modify the controller accessControl like so :

```
public function accessRules()
    {
        return array(
            array('allow',  // allow all users to perform 'index' and 'view' actions
                'actions'=>array('index','view','captcha'),
                'users'=>array('*'),
            ),
            array('allow', // allow authenticated user to perform every action
                'actions'=>array('create','update','admin','delete'),
                'users'=>array('@'),
            ),

            array('deny',  // deny all users
                'users'=>array('*'),
            ),
        );
    }
```