# The captcha doesn't display the image using Yii

Tags: php, yii, captcha

I have just realized that my captcha doesn't display the images, is like if it was broke. I'm sure that before it works well, but I don't know what happened.

So, the first thing that I did was to change the model, view and controller edited for my for the original created using Yii, but now it dosen't work either...

Now I have the following controller (the originals created by Yii):

```
<?php

class SiteController extends Controller
{
/**
 * Declares class-based actions.
 */
public function actions()
{
    return array(
        // captcha action renders the CAPTCHA image displayed on the contact page
        'captcha'=>array(
            'class'=>'CCaptchaAction',
            'backColor'=>0xFFFFFF,
        ),
        // page action renders "static" pages stored under 'protected/views/site/pages'
        // They can be accessed via: index.php?r=site/page&view=FileName
        'page'=>array(
            'class'=>'CViewAction',
        ),
    );
}

    ...
```

The model:

```
<?php

/**
 * ContactForm class.
 * ContactForm is the data structure for keeping
 * contact form data. It is used by the 'contact' action of 'SiteController'.
*/
class ContactForm2 extends CFormModel
{
public $name;
public $email;
public $subject;
public $body;
public $verifyCode;

/**
 * Declares the validation rules.
 */

public function rules()
{
    return array(
        // name, email, subject and body are required
        array('name, email, subject, body', 'required'),
        // email has to be a valid email address
        array('email', 'email'),
        // verifyCode needs to be entered correctly
        array('verifyCode', 'captcha', 'allowEmpty'=>!CCaptcha::checkRequirements()),
    );
}

...
```

and the view:

```
       ...

    <?php if(CCaptcha::checkRequirements()): ?>
        <div class="row">
            <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'verifyCode'); ?>
            <div>
                <?php $this->widget('CCaptcha'); ?>
                <?php echo $form->textField($model,'verifyCode'); ?>
            </div>
            <div class="hint">Please enter the letters as they are shown in the image above.
                <br/>Letters are not case-sensitive.</div>
            <?php echo $form->error($model,'verifyCode'); ?>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>

     ...
```

I think that my problem may be like the reported in the [following link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11895376/ccaptcha-displaying-no-image-yii), so I also used the follow accessRules()

```
public function rules()
{
return array(
    array('allow',
     'actions' => array('captcha'), 
     'users' => array('*'),
     ),
);
}
```

and

```
public function rules()
{
    return array(
        array('allow', 
            'actions'=>array('create', 'captcha'),
            'users'=>array('*'),
        )
    );
}
```

But both gave me errors:

"ContactForm2 tiene una regla de validación inválida. La regla se debe especificar attributos para ser validados y el nombre de su validador."

Please, someone could help me? Why is happening this? I read a lot about this topic, but I didn't find the solution...

Comment: check this forum: http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/20087-captcha-validator-dont-work-properly/

Comment: @kumar_v thanks, I also searched for there, but I didn't find anything :(

Comment: did you set `'testLimit' => 2,`?

Comment: @Kumar_v I don't understand you, could explain what are you reffering to me?

Comment: You didn't check my link. That's why you didn't understand.

Comment: @kumar_v thanks. I read your link, and I understood that ours problems were different, since I don't have any problem with the validation, my problem is that I can't see the captcha image. Even so, I tried what you said ('testLimit' => 2) but it doesn't work.

Comment: check the error in firebug. What exactly is the error? is it "not found" or "permission denied". Also, accessRules is different from rules. The one used in controller is accessRules

Comment: @franki It is a validation problem: "[...] regla de validación inválida [...]".
Please show as the full log of errors.

Comment: @sadaf and and Jorge B.G thanks. I'm sorry to reply so late. In the end, I could fixed the bug, I had the caracters "?>" at the end of one of files that I uploaded recently. When I removed these caracters the captcha was displayed again.