# PHP 7.1.7 imagecreatetruecolor produces 500 error

Tags: php, iis

I have been updating my site to PHP 7.1.7 as well as IIS and have run into an issue with imagecreatetrucolor throwing a 500 error.

```
http://localhost/test.php 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

The only line of code in that file is

```
<?php imagecreatetruecolor(10,10) ?>
```

This has been working in the site under PHP 5.6.31 and Apache and returns

```
resource(2) of type (gd)
```

GD imaging is listed in with phpinfo() under 7.1.7 as

```
GD imaging  Rasmus Lerdorf, Stig Bakken, Jim Winstead, Jouni Ahto, Ilia Alshanetsky, Pierre-Alain Joye, Marcus Boerger
```

This is the error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function imagecreatetruecolor() in D:\Intranet\www\public\test.php:11 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in D:\Intranet\www\public\test.php on line 11
```

What could the problem be?

Comment: Turn On you error reporting from Your ini file to see what's the error !!

Comment: This is the error

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function imagecreatetruecolor() in D:\Intranet\www\public\test.php:11 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in D:\Intranet\www\public\test.php on line 11

Comment: so Your function is not defined !

Comment: It is a built in function in PHP how can it not be defined?

Comment: Note: adding header("Content-Type: image/png"); before the call to the function works but generates a black page.

Comment: make sure that you have also updated  php-gd to php7.1-gd and check this out it could helpful  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4560996/call-to-undefined-function-imagecreatetruecolor-error-in-php-pchart

Comment: Did a fresh install of 7.1 so not sure why it wouldn't be. Will have a look, thanks.

Comment: OK that was it. php_gd2.dll was not enabled, didn't even think about that as it was the php.ini from 5.6 so I'm not sure why it wouldn't have been. The thread you posted didn't show in any of my searches, would have saved my a couple hours and you your time. 

Please post this as an answer so that I can up vote it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comment  Make sure that you have installed `php7.1-gd` and it is enabled

Check out this answer it could be helpful
[call-to-undefined-function-imagecreatetruecolor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4560996/call-to-undefined-function-imagecreatetruecolor-error-in-php-pchart)

Comment: To be specific I had to uncomment extension=php_gd2.dll in the php.ini. I also had to uncomment extension=php_exif.dll to be able to work with the exif data in the file to ensure that the site continued to work as it should. 

Thanks for the help.